# How to forbid instances of different classes in Java list?

Tags: java, list

Let's say I have method `doSomething(List<A> list)` and I have abstract class `A` and concrete classes `B` and `C` that implements `A`.

So I want to say to client to pass list of `B` objects or list of `C` objects but I don't want to make possible for him to pass 3 `B` objects and 2 `C` objects in one list.

One solution is to add new parameter "type" and to check if all instances are of the same class but that solution doesn't seem "elegant" to me.

It would be great if I can annotate method something like `@SameConcreteClasses` or something like that so caller can see what I expect.

Comment: Sounds like you should use generics `doSomething(List<B> list)` and `doSomething(List<C> list)`

Comment: One perhaps not so elegant solution would be to check all the elements in the list via  list.get(i) instanceof B or list.get(i) instanceof C and if the list constains mixed elements, don't instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you're supposed to use inheritance in Java.

Your list collects items of class type A. Any object iterating that list will be assured that all methods of class type A are available and respond with values of type defined in A.

If you need the methods provided in class B or C then I would suggest you add an interface that supports methods you require in your pipeline, add that to your classes and then any method using it can be accessed further in the pipeline, no matter the type of the class that was added to the `List<MyInterface>`

You want the developer to know what methods you're expecting/requiring, that's also basically the textbook definition of an interface.
It's your hint to the future developer to say: *"I need methods a,b,c and z defined to return such and so types. I don't care how you build it, or if you mock it, as long as these methods are available to me."*
And you can rest assured that your methods calls will not throw errors, you might only get the occasional null returned.

Think about your pipeline first, and what methods they need available.
Then write an interface for those methods.
Then add that interface to the applicable classes.
Then make the list only accept items having that interface.

```
class A {
   protected int count = 1;
   public int getCount() {
      return this.count;
   }
}
class B extends A{
   private String name = "B";
   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
}
class C {
   private String name = "C";
   public int getCount() {
      return 20;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

Lets say at the end of the pipeline that has collected all the classes we have a method:

```
public void outputFull(List<????> output) {
     for(???? item : output) {
          if(item.getCount() > 1) {
              System.out.println(item.getName() + " has " + item.getCount() + " items");
          }
     }
}
```

I marked the type with ??? since we *'don't know yet what we need'*

So from our final method where it's passed through the pipeline we know we need objects that have a `int getCount()` and a `String getName()` method.

We can write an interface for that:

```
public interface INamedCountable {
    public int getCount();
    public String getName();
}
```

And with that interface we can turn our wished objects into that interface type

```
class A {
   protected int count = 1;
   public int getCount() {
      return this.count;
   }
}
class B extends A implements INamedCountable {
   private String name = "B";
   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
}
class C implements INamedCountable {
   private String name = "C";
   public int getCount() {
      return 20;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

And for our pipeline we can then use:

```
public void outputFull(List<INamedCountable> output) {
     for(INamedCountable item : output) {
          if(item.getCount() > 1) {
              System.out.println(item.getName() + " has " + item.getCount() + " items");
          }
     }
}
public void runPipe() {
   List<INamedCountable> pipeline = new ArrayList<INamedCountable>();
   pipeline.add(new B());
   pipeline.add(new C());
   outputFull(pipeline);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add additional parameter `Class<A>` and use [Generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) to synchronize types of two arguments

```
private <T extends A> void doSomething(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {

}


    doSomething(new ArrayList<B>(), B.class);
    doSomething(new ArrayList<C>(), C.class);
    doSomething(new ArrayList<B>(), C.class); <-- compile error here
    doSomething(new ArrayList<A>(), B.class);<-- compile error here
```

It will force to client to decide what actual class he want to pass in method, but still could be passed with `doSomething(new ArrayList<A>(), A.class);`

Another solution to extract `doSomething` to interface (abstract class) and make two implementations for it:

```
 private abstract class ExecutorForA<T extends A> {
     private void doSomething(List<T> list) {
    }
 }

 private class ExecutorForB extends ExecutorForA<B> {
 }
 private class ExecutorForC extends ExecutorForA<C> {
 }
```